# Change a tkinter label text every fragment of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-text

I want to **simulate loading** on my GUI app but I can't. I'm trying to do this by changing a label text at the bottom of the root through intervals of time, as you can see in my simple code.
I want it to work like this:

- The label text is **"Please wait"** at first.
- After 0.5s, it will change    to **"Please wait."** then **"Please wait.."**,
  **"Please wait..."** and then the process is on repeat until reaching
  a specific amount of seconds of waiting.

The problem with my code is that the sleep method (time module) that I used repeatedly will freeze the program until reaching the time limit, which means that **"window.mainloop"** will not be executed until the end of the loop. And it will only display the last label text value accessed.
here is my code:

```
#

from tkinter import *
import time

window=Tk()

#windowinfo
window.geometry("1080x720")
window.title("")
window.config(bg="#00FFFF")
lrd=PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/hp/OneDrive/Desktop/hhh.png")
ver=Label(window,image=lrd,bd=10,relief=RIDGE)
ver.pack(expand=YES)
wait=Label(window,text="Please wait")
wait.pack(side=BOTTOM)
t=0
while t<4:
    wait.config(text="Please wait.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    t+=1
    wait.config(text="Please wait..")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    t+=1
    wait.config(text="Please wait...")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    t+=1
#F8D210
#window display
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Look at `.after` scripts. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801) looks like a good explanation

Comment: Create a list with all the transitional text then increase the variable by one and use `after` inside a function

Comment: It seems that .after is what I'm looking for, thanks to you guys

Comment: @CoolCloud You can do it that way but it will be a waste of memory. You can generate the text on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")

wait = tk.Label(window, text="Please wait")
wait.pack()

def loop(t=0):
    if t < 12:
        # Change the Label's text
        wait.config(text="Please wait" + "." * (t % 3 + 1))
        # Schedule a call to `loop` in 500 milliseconds with t+1 as a parameter
        window.after(500, loop, t+1)

# Start the loop
loop()

window.mainloop()
```

It uses a [`.after`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801) loop. It calls `loop` every 500 milliseconds while incrementing `t`.

The `t % 3` cycles between 0, 1, 2 repeatedly. I just added one to all of them to make it: 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: @CoolCloud This is faster and would use less memory, given that you know how `t % 3` is going to cycle: 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2.

Comment: Ah well, I do not know about memory consumption of this vs list indexing

Comment: @CoolCloud This removes the strings from memory after the `.config`. And this would be more practical if you wanted to just wait for some event like a process to finish. You can replace the `t < 12` with any condition.

Comment: @TheLizzard thank u so much, I was still struggling with the .after method but now I understand it completely with your code